# Is there a UWP friendly program or Windows 10 API that is like RoboCopy?

Tags: uwp, windows-10-universal, robocopy

I have an old .Net Forms app that calls [Robocopy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robocopy).  Basically the app allows you to carefully save Robocopy args (source, destination and options) in a DB for consistent reuse.

I'd like to rebuild the app in UWP but UWP security restrictions deliberately disallow you to make command calls to .exe's.

Is there a substitute to Robocopy that I could call from UWP?  Like some sort of Windows 10 API, Powershell or something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you want to run this robocopy feature only on desktop (not on phones or HoloLens devices), you can use the FullTrustProcessLauncher API from the UWP Desktop extension SDK:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/Windows.ApplicationModel.FullTrustProcessLauncher

With this you can launch your own full trust process on desktop (for example a console or headless app) that is not subject to UWP restrictions. From there you can call robocopy or whatever else you need to run.

I have tutorial here on my blog:
https://stefanwick.com/2018/04/06/uwp-with-desktop-extension-part-1/